# ListView requires two clicks to select on touch

Tags: wpf, listview, touch

I have a ListView that looks like this:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="LocationList" 
          BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
          Margin="50,20,20,50" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" />
```

And a style and control template like this:

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >

        <ContentControl SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Name="ListStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,3,3"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works as expected when using a mouse; hovering the cursor over a list item activates the "IsMouseOver" style and clicking it activates the "IsSelected" style. However, when using a touch screen clicking on a list item only activates the "IsMouseOver" style and the item is not selected, to select it I have to click the same item again. When holding the finger down (causing a cursor to appear) the "IsMouseOver" style is not activated when I drag my finger across it.

Comment: If you want use the list as the main component in the windows you can set `LocationList.Focust()`on your Loaded event, i think it should work.

Comment: Removing the "IsMouseOver" trigger fixed it, but now I have no hover style... can anyone explain why this trigger broke the list on touch screens only and if there's some way to work around this?